# Laravel validations: opposite of exists (value should not exist in the given table,column)

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have table `employee` that has a nullable column `substitute` referencing to another employee. The API I'm developing can receive a DELETE request for `/employee/{employee_id}` and it should validate employee_id to make sure it is not referenced by any other row. So basically, I need a validation rule like this:

```
Validator::make($data, [
    'employee_id' => '!exists:employee,substitute'
], [
    '!exists' => 'Employee :employee_id cannot be deleted as it is being used as substitute for other employees' // custom message
])
```

Does Laravel have something similar out of the box or should I define custom validation rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use `unique` rule or **create a new rule**

```php
'employee_id' => 'unique:employee,substitute'
```

Or

```php
Validator::extend('not_exists', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
  $exists = DB::table($parameters[0])
    ->where($parameters[1], '=', $value)
    ->exists();

  return $exists === false;
});
```

Comment: Unique doesn't make sense in this use case. I want to only delete eamploye with given ID, if that ID is not being used as reference in the substitute column.

Comment: It does not matter what you are gonna do after that, you want to know if the value does not exist already, then use unique, it's like a trick in this case

Comment: The first option is irrelevant to the question, but creating the `not_exists` rule may work just fine.

Comment: @balintant if value  is unique doesn't  it mean that it does not exist on the table?

Comment: @MahdiYounesi could work, but you missed the either the parent field or the comparison column, resulting in `false` all the time.
On the other side, it's not that straightforward (talking about English, and not PHP) resulting in a hack/workaround. At least, I feel about it like that.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up extending validator to create `not_exists` rule. I was hoping that laravel has something similar out of the box.

Comment: @MahdiYounesi the right code is `->where($parameters[1], '=', $value)`